# Ошибка "Не удалось найти строку подключения с именем ... в файле конфигурации приложения"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, ado.net

Приложение реализует паттерн MVC и работает с базой данных (MS SQL Server). Бизнес-логика реализована в отдельном проекте в виде библиотеки классов, там же находятся модель ADO.NET, методы для обращения к БД, строка подключения добавлена в параметры и прописана в app.config. Использовалась модель Database First.

При таком построении приложение не может сделать запрос к БД, появляется ошибка *"Не удалось найти строку подключения с именем ... в файле конфигурации приложения"*. Я так понимаю, что приложение ищет строку подключения в файле App.config проекта, где реализованы Controller и View. А там ее нет, т.к. она в проекте библиотеки классов, где реализована Model. Как правильно решить такую проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Приложение ищет строку подключения в файле <имя запускаемого файла>.exe.config. Определите какой проект у вас запускается, строку подключения нужно скопировать в этот проект в файл app.config, скомпилируйте и запустите.